# Internet Explorer browsers request extra 'none/' pages for all pages on my website

Tags: internet-explorer

Yesterday I decided to use PHP's `error_log` for sending error messages to my e-mail address. Soon I received hundreds of letters, telling me that there were attempts to load '%some_page%/**none/**' links. For example, user tries to load the page with the relative link 'contacts/', this page is loaded and displayed correctly, but there is also the request to 'contacts/**none/**' page, so my web-server needs to handle twice more requests. All these requests were from IE users only. I tried myself to load several pages with IE 8, they were displayed correctly, but the browser also tried to load these stupid '/none' pages.

The **same error** was described [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/none-at-the-end-of-permalinks?replies=6#post-1096316), but the solution was not found. I don't use any CMS. My website passes W3 markup validation without any errors. I really don't know what to do and cannot find any helpful information about this problem in the Web.
[image]
Screenshot of Chrome's DevTools.[image]
**LAST UPDATE**:
I figured out that was because of css rules 'behavior: url(/custom/css/border-radius.htc);'. I removed them and everything worked!

Comment: Any `background: url(none);` (or `background-image`) in your CSS?

Comment: Well, I'm sure that there are no such things in code, written by myself, but I use some other modules like CKEditor and FancyBox, so it is hard to ensure that everything is correct with them. In CKeditor css rules are generated automatically somewhere, so it is hard enough to check evertything. Anyway, I'll try to disable all these modules for a while and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: It might be quicker to check using the Network or Console tabs of Chrome's DevTools to see if there are any `404`s. It's difficult to detect with validation tools since `background: url(none);` is perfectly valid CSS!

Comment: First, I tried to exclude all CSS and JS files except of mine, this didn't help. Then I tried to do as you said and check Chrome's DevTools. There are no not found elements. Screenshot is in my updated post.

Comment: Does it happen with other browsers?

Comment: I also tried PHPStorm's "Find in Path" for the string '(none)', no occurrences in the whole project.

Comment: @andyb I figured out that was because of css rules 'behavior: url(/custom/css/border-radius.htc);'. I removed them and everything worked! But that's quite strange.

Comment: Perhaps, I downloaded incorrect border-radius.htc file, which had errors inside. Anyway, I suppose rounded borders are not so important.

Comment: Good to hear you resolved it! You could add that as an answer and accept it if you want. It might also earn you some up votes :-)

Comment: OK, I'll write an answer, but first I need to find exactly the reason of the error in this file, and try to offer another, working file, if it exists, so that answer will be more informative.

Comment: My 'border-radius.htc' file was downloaded from the reliable source, http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/. I tried to understand the reason of the error, analyzing this file's source code, but it's not so obvious. So, I couldn't find the exact reason of the error, just simple solution of my problem, so, I suppose, it would be incorrect to post this as an answer. And I also tried CSS PIE http://css3pie.com/, it works perfectly without any errors.